# Hibernate Cascade delete for one-to-many call SQL "update" instead of "delete"

Tags: hibernate

I have a simple parent / children obj bi-directional relationship defined.  I want to perform cascade delete so that when parent is removed, all the children would be removed as well with one 1 delete call from parent.  Here are my pojo class declaration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Agent_Assignment", schema = "xxx", catalog = "AAA")
public class AgentAssignment {
    private Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> attributes = new HashSet<AgentAssignmentAttr>();

    @OneToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true )
    @JoinColumn(name="Agent_Assignment_GUID")
    public Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Agent_Assignment_Attr", schema = "xxx", catalog = "AAA")
public class AgentAssignmentAttr {
    private AgentAssignment asgnmnt = null;

    @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name="Agent_Assignment_GUID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public AgentAssignment getAssignment() {
        return asgnmnt;
    }

    public void setAssignment(AgentAssignment assignment) {
        this.asgnmnt = assignment;
    }
}
```

And the code to delete is:

```
AgentAssignment assgnmnt = (...some HQL query to returns the AgentAssignment obj)
getSession().delete(assgnmnt);
```

When execute the above delete call, it throws exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Basically, when log at the Hibernate log's SQL being executed, it doesn't call "update" on Agent_Assignment_Attr table's row it supposed to delete, but instead call "update" on the row to set the foreign key column "Agent_Assignement_GUID" to null, as shown below:

```
/* delete one-to-many com.cs.mytime.acr.model.AgentAssignment.attributes */ update
        MyTime.dbo.Agent_Assignment_Attr 
    set
        Agent_Assignment_GUID=null 
    where
        Agent_Assignment_GUID=?
2014/08/22 16:31:10.430 [TRACE] <http-bio-8080-exec-5> (BasicBinder.bind:81) - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [CA91A4F3-6F7E-4188-B299-8E9DF17F0385]
```

Appreciate anybody to help to see if there's something I have missed and the right solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. A bidirectional assocition must only define how the association is mapped **once**. What you have there is two distinct, unrelated associations that happen to use the same column. The mapping should be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="assignment", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true )
public Set<AgentAssignmentAttr> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}
```

where `mappedBy` says: "I'm the inverse side of the bidirectional association defined and mapped on `AgentAssignmentAttr.assignment`, and

```
@ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn(name="Agent_Assignment_GUID")
public AgentAssignment getAssignment() {
    return asgnmnt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I changed it according to what you said, but the issue still persisted.  Still call "update" and complains about setting the Agent_Assignment_GUID to null, where Agent_Assignment_GUID has constraiin of can't be NULL in D.

Comment: add `optional = false` to your ManyToOne annotation.

Comment: Actually, I take the previous comment back.  Nizet, when I changed it to:
 @OneToMany( mappedBy="asgnmnt", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,  cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
  
 it throws the following exception when starting the server:
 Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.cs.mytime.acr.model.AgentAssignmentAttr.asgnmnt in com.cs.mytime.acr.model.AgentAssignment.attributes

Comment: Well did I write `mappedBy = "asgnmnt"` in my answer?

Comment: mappedBy="xxx" where xxx should be equal to the variable name of the parent class, which is "asgnmnt", in the children class AgentAssignmentAttr, right?

Comment: No, not right. You placed the annotation on the getter, not on the field. And the getter is `getAssignment()`. That said, why the hello don't you name your field assignment, instead of the unreadable asgnmnt? You're making your own life dificult.

Comment: Yeah, it works now.  Many thanks.  I did try to use mappedBy earlier today as you suggested and it failed and therefore switched to use JoinColumn as described in the Hibernate docs.  Anyway, glad that it works now.

Comment: BTW, Nizet, may I ask what's the purpose of optional = false?

Comment: It tells Hibernate that it can't set this column to null, because the association is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a **delete** instead of an **update** I had to use this approach:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", updatable = false)
private List<ChildEntity> children;
```